# Getting index of selected tree item in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am trying a GWT application. I have a Tree which has a lot of tree items. I want to retrieve the index of an item selected in the tree. I see that Tree class does not have a method like getSelectedElementIndex(). Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register and `SelectionHandler`, via `addSelectionHandler`. The event given when a item is selected returns the selected `TreeItem` object.

Also `Tree` has a method `getSelectedItem()`, which returns a `TreeItem`. The class `TreeItem` has a method `getChildIndex` that takes a `TreeItem` and returns the index. Futhermore, with `item.getParentItem().getChildIndex(item)` you should get the index of that item.

Comment: item.getParentItem() returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function to do this:

```
int getTreeItemIndex(Tree tree, TreeItem item)
{
    int count = tree.getItemCount();
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        TreeItem test = tree.getItem(i);
        if (test == item)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This will only search the direct children of a Tree object, and return -1 if it wasn't found.

Answer (score -1):

When you render each tree item, you can store the index as setLayoutData. When you require you can get it from getLayoutData. Any object can be stored here. I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I wasn't able to use setLayoutData method for a TreeItem object, despite importing java.lang.Object.

Comment: Yes I am wrong. Since TreeItem is an UIObject not a Widget extension, you can't call the setLayoutData method on TreeItem.